# Link to view in Area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this folder structure for some views in an **Area**, specifically **Admin**:

[image: Admin Folder Structure]

I try to link to a view called **Account Currencies** as follows:

```
<a id="accountCurrencies" class="dropdown-item" asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="AccountCurrencies" asp-action="Index">Account Currencies</a>
```

I get this error - URL automatically generated by link above:
[image: Error]

How do I get this page to show correctly?

**Tried different combinations of linking to the view with no success.**

Comment: views are resolved by using controllers - show your Index method in AccountCurrencies controller. Also, I've never seen area being resolved through query parameters, is it a thing? Also try to paste  /admin/accountcurrencies in URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have Controllers with the `[Area]` attribute to associate the controller with the area:

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class AccountCurrenciesController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You can have a look at [Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to know more.